# powershell foreach shows duplicate result

Tags: powershell, foreach

I use powershell to automate extracting of selected data from a CSV file.
My $target_servers also contains two the same server name but it has different data in each rows.

Here is my code:

```
$target_servers = Get-Content -Path  D:\Users\Tools\windows\target_prd_servers.txt
foreach($server in $target_servers) {
    Import-Csv $path\Serverlist_Template.csv | Where-Object {$_.Hostname -Like $server} | Export-Csv -Path $path/windows_prd.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

After executing the above code it extracts CSV data based on a TXT file, but my problem is some of the results are duplicated.

I am expecting around 28 results but it gave me around 49.

Comment: Your logic looks roughly ok. However your output depends on the content of those files so try checking there first. If you still need help then give us an extract of that data to look into

Comment: Looks like `-Append` is the culprit here. Since you are appending to an already existing csv file **without** checking if those records will be a duplicate or not, I think duplicates are unavoidable.

Comment: Check out [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance on future questions.  Well formed questions are more likely to get good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, `-Append` is the culprit here and you should check if the newly added records are not already present in the output file:

```
# read the Hostname column of the target csv file as array to avoid duplicates
$existingHostsNames = @((Import-Csv -Path "$path/windows_prd.csv").Hostname)

$target_servers = Get-Content -Path  D:\Users\Tools\windows\target_prd_servers.txt
foreach($server in $target_servers) {
    Import-Csv "$path\Serverlist_Template.csv" |
         Where-Object {($_.Hostname -eq $server) -and ($existingHostsNames -notcontains $_.HostName)} | 
         Export-Csv -Path "$path/windows_prd.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Hi,

I'm Thankful for this helpful tip on how append works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your data to array of objects and then use `select -Unique`, like this:

```
$target_servers = Get-Content -Path  D:\Users\Tools\windows\target_prd_servers.txt

$data = @()
foreach($server in $target_servers) {
    $data += Import-Csv $path\Serverlist_Template.csv| Where-Object {$_.Hostname -Like $server}
}
$data | select -Unique | Export-Csv -Path $path/windows_prd.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

It will work only if duplicated rows have same value in every column. If not, you can pass column names to `select` which are important for you. For ex.:

```
$data | select Hostname -Unique | Export-Csv -Path $path/windows_prd.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

It will give you list of unique hostnames.